# Batch update fires all requests

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to make an update with `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` like this:

```
oModel.setUseBatch(true);
oModel.setDeferredGroups(["batchUpdateGroup"]);


oModel.update("/myPath", myData1, {
    groupId: "batchUpdateGroup"
    merge: false
});


oModel.update("/myPath", myData2, {
    groupId: "batchUpdateGroup"
    merge: false
});

oModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: "batchUpdateGroup",
    success: function(oData) {
        console.log("Success!");
    },
    error: function(oError) {
        console.log("Error!");
    }
});
```

`submitChanges` fires the update but also other requests from the model like read requests or bindings. What am i doing wrong with the "groupId"?

Answer (score 1):

Because you use wrong syntax of [update](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#update) method.

The right one looks like this:

```
oModel.update("/myPath", myData1, {
    groupId: "batchUpdateGroup"
});
```

P.S. if you do not know whether you need to use "changeId", do not use it.

**UPD:**
Also the [refreshAfterChange](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#setRefreshAfterChange) updates all the bindings that your updated entity were involved in.

Comment: Sorry, the bracket was a typo. I've changed my code (removed parameters object) but same happens. :-(

Comment: did you clear cache? do you see these changes in your "source" tab of chrome dev tools? which ui5 version are you using?

Comment: you mentioned that "read" requests are fired, it's because "refreshAfterChange" property is set to true. Are you sure that other crap requests get triggered?

Comment: Yes. All requests i've done before in the app like `/mySet?$skip=0&$top=500&$filter=reference="2001675873"&$expand=expandSet`

Comment: If this request belongs to table (you bind table using this path) and you update one of the table's items, it might be the reason that "refreshAfterChange" does.. Did you try to switch it off? because it's "true" by default.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, `oModel.setRefreshAfterChange(false);` and it works. "_Defines whether **all bindings** are updated after a change operation._" Thank you. :-)